# Moved Bitcoin-Qt wallet to blockchain - can see my funds but can't send them?

Tags: blockchain.info, lost-bitcoins

It all started the other day when I sent some coins to Bitcoin-Qt, a 'safer' wallet ... was so slow to sync and was crashing et cetera.

Anyway, I imported the wallet.dat to blockchain.info opening up a mywallet(blockchain) there. I can see the coins in the wallet now, but I can't send them (no access to send option), which is what I have to do.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Is the address on blockchain marked as 'watch only'?

Comment: I don't know. I can't see anything to indicate it is. It allows me to receive (an address)but no option to send. Ive completeled all security tasks , email verification and sms verifiction but no joy

Comment: Try importing the private key string directly into a blockchain wallet.

Comment: Ok..this makes me nervous. I'm no techie and am afraid ill f it up

Comment: How should I get the private key?

Comment: OK. I worked out how to extract the priv key. I did so and then exported( drag and dop) into blockchain mywallet. It says it already has that 'address' Now what?

Answer (score -1):

i have blockchain.info "My Wallet" wallet on iphone. i didn't pay any attention to it for about a month until a couple of days ago. when i opened the app it showed a balance of 0.00 BTC. A momentary shock. Then i noticed that the "identifier" i.e., the string of letters and numbers in the top field. This is your public key for that block. For some reason in its wisdom blockchain created a new identifier that now by default fills the identifier field, whereas my old correct identifier used to show in that field, and a positive BTC balance associated with that idedentifier showed as well. Now when I hand enter the old correct identifier, it shows my correct BTC balance.

1. I do not appreciate having the functionality of the app change like that without notice to me first.
2. Contacting support from blockchain is impossible if there is any support from blockchain.

To answer your question: hand enter your original identifier and your correct account will show. I have no idea why they change one's identifier.